# UILabel is nil when sending the text from UITextView to another class

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the two view controllers I am trying to transfer the text from. Whenever it is moved to the other class it becomes nil.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageTextLabel: UILabel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageTextLabel?.text = "Initial String For Label"
    }

    func changeLabelText(){
        print("Inside of View Controller:", "\(AddNoteViewController.GlobalVariable.textViewData)")
        imageTextLabel?.text = "Whats up"
        print(imageTextLabel?.text ?? "Default")

        imageTextLabel?.text = (AddNoteViewController.GlobalVariable.textViewData)
    }
}

import UIKit

class AddNoteViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewController = ViewController()

    @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    struct GlobalVariable{
        static var textViewData = "Start String"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        GlobalVariable.textViewData = textView.text
        viewController.changeLabelText()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        print(GlobalVariable.textViewData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if your outlet is connected to the storyboard.

Comment: AddNoteViewController this view controller first then you can send text from one controller to another controller.

let vc = AddNoteViewController() 
vc.getDataFromViewController = "Your text"
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

getDataFromViewController is string variable in AddNoteViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SWIFT 4 / Xcode 10**

In this case you are trying to set a label text before loading viewController. When there is no viewController, the program does not know the label (xcode sees no imageTextLabel?.text to set a text for you). therefore, you need to set your text when the view is going/did appear.

There are easiest way to implement passing texts. but in your example you can implement 'viewDidAppear' inside your viewController and call your function inside it. (As below)

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    changeLabelText()

    //or just set the text here:
    //self.imageTextLabel?.text = AddNoteViewController.GlobalVariable.textViewData
}
```

And remove 'viewController.changeLabelText()' from the 'AddNoteViewController' class.

Answer (score 0):

The viewController in   AddNoteViewController is different from the one in your storyboard.  var viewController = ViewController() is not enough. In viewDidAppear, try to point the right ViewController to the viewController.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var imageTextLabel: UILabel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageTextLabel?.text = "Initial String For Label"
}

func changeLabelText(){
    print("Inside of View Controller:", "\  (AddNoteViewController.GlobalVariable.textViewData)")
    imageTextLabel?.text = "Whats up"
    print(imageTextLabel?.text ?? "Default")

     imageTextLabel?.text = (AddNoteViewController.GlobalVariable.textViewData)
    }
   }

  import UIKit

 class AddNoteViewController: UIViewController {
        var viewController = ViewController() // it's not the right viewController. 

      @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
      @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    struct GlobalVariable{
        static var textViewData = "Start String"
     }

     override  func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    viewController = // point to your viewController here??
   }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    viewController =  
   }

  @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
     GlobalVariable.textViewData = textView.text
      viewController.changeLabelText()
     dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

     print(GlobalVariable.textViewData)
  }
  }
```